# Macro says ' End if with out block if ' but all the if blocks are there

Tags: vba, excel

i have writen a macro to get some excel data from one sheet to another so that i can use the data easily according to conditions

```
Sub page(rowNumber As Integer)

    Dim row_number As Integer
    Dim iterator As Integer
    Dim srch_string As String ' Searching for the string view
    Dim IdMethod As String
    Dim UIValues As String
    Dim Name As String
    Dim SheetName As String
    Dim number As Integer
    Dim result As String

    result = " "
    IdMethod = " "
    UIValues = " "
    row_number = rowNumber
    iterator = row_number
    Name = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
    srch_string = "onclick"
    number = 3
    SheetName = "page"
    Application.Worksheets(SheetName).Activate
    'while   i= rowNumber
    Do While iterator > 0
        If srch_string = Worksheets(SheetName).Cells(iterator, 5) Then
          Exit Do
        Else
          IdMethod = IdMethod & ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetName).Cells(iterator, 4)
          UIValues = UIValues & ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetName).Cells(iterator, 5)
          For Index = 2 To Worksheets("param").UsedRange.Rows.Count
             If ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetName).Cells(iterator, 5) = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("param").Cells(Index, 1) Then
                    Do While munber > 0
                        If result <> srch_string Then
                            Exit Do
                        Else
                            result = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetName).Cells(iterator, 5)
                            ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("param").Cells(number, 1) = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetName).Cells(iterator, 5)
                            number = number + 1
                            iterator = iterator - 1
                        End If
             End If
             iterator = iterator - 1
    End If
    Loop
    End Sub
```

but the macro says End if with out block if ... 
am not sure about all the syntaxes
but all the ifs are placed correctly as far as i know not able to figure out what went wrong

Comment: there are two thing with your code: 1) you've missed `Next Index` for `For Index =2 ...` and 2) you've missed `Loop` for `Do While munber > 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing Next Index that closes

```
    For Index = 2 To Worksheets("param").UsedRange.Rows.Count
```

**EDIT**

And as @simoco and @brain pointed out, you also need also to close Do While nunber > 0 with `Loop`.

Comment: I dint know that we have close Do while with loop stmt Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

```
Sub page(rowNumber As Integer)

    Dim row_number As Integer
    Dim iterator As Integer
    Dim srch_string As String ' Searching for the string view
    Dim IdMethod As String
    Dim UIValues As String
    Dim Name As String
    Dim SheetName As String
    Dim number As Integer
    Dim result As String

    result = " "
    IdMethod = " "
    UIValues = " "
    row_number = rowNumber
    iterator = row_number
    Name = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
    srch_string = "onclick"
    number = 3
    SheetName = "page"
    Application.Worksheets(SheetName).Activate
    'while   i= rowNumber
    Do While iterator > 0
        If srch_string = Worksheets(SheetName).Cells(iterator, 5) Then
          Exit Do
        Else
          IdMethod = IdMethod & ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetName).Cells(iterator, 4)
          UIValues = UIValues & ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetName).Cells(iterator, 5)
          For Index = 2 To Worksheets("param").UsedRange.Rows.Count
             If ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetName).Cells(iterator, 5) = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("param").Cells(Index, 1) Then
                    Do While munber > 0
                        If result <> srch_string Then
                            Exit Do
                        Else
                            result = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetName).Cells(iterator, 5)
                            ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("param").Cells(number, 1) = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetName).Cells(iterator, 5)
                            number = number + 1
                            iterator = iterator - 1
                        End If
                   Next '<- Add Next Here (Missing in your code)
             End If
         Next '<- Add Next Here (Missing in your code)
             iterator = iterator - 1
    End If
    Loop
    End Sub
```

Comment: Hi am getting Next with out for :(